# Suffixing by "-rama", "-orama" or "-arama" — how did this begin?

Tags: etymology, nouns, suffixes

Suffixing by *-rama, -orama* or *-arama* — how did this begin? I mean words like *futurama, foodarama*, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=-rama&searchmode=none) to the rescue:

> **-rama** noun suffix meaning "spectacular display or instance of," 1824, abstracted from *panorama*, ultimately from Greek *horama* [*ὅραμα*] "sight."

Comment: Exactly! Note that the (ho)ra- part comes from horaô, "to see"; and -ma, genitive -matos, is a suffix mostly used to make a noun out of a verb, if I am not mistaken. The correct use of the suffix would be to use -orama, so futurorama, or foodorama... but English usually doesn't listen to correctness, especially not when creating fun words!

Comment: @Cerberus: There is a "correct" way to add Greek suffixes to English words? Do you have a link or a citation?

Comment: @hippietrail: Well it might not matter so much to everyone. Besides, -orama is mostly used with a meaning that doesn't have anything to do with its meaning in Greek anyway. But if one were seriously creating a scientific word with components from foreign languages, generally such components need to be used with their original stem intact, and with the correct connecting vowel if used as a prefix. For example, if you wanted to create a new word à la monopoly, you'd need to know that the root of the first component is mon-, not mono-: monarchy, not monoarchy. Then there is contraction...

Answer (score 3):

Briefly, *diorama* and *panorama* were popular in Napoleonic times, if not before, and came into and out of fashion as such words do.  Specifically, they enjoyed a vogue after WW2, when film-makers were looking for impressive names for their colour and widescreen films (Colorama, Futurama, Technorama, etc- probably influenced by *drama*, but not directly connected).    The vogue led to many bottle stores, for example, renaming themselves *liquoramas* to draw in customers, though there is no plausible meaning for this, let alone etymology.  Mercifully, the fashion seems to have died away.
 (Thanks to The Straight Dope, as referenced above: but their article's too long to quote directly).

Comment: I'm surprised no one mentioned *pleasureama*.

Answer (score 2):

There's a long article on this on The Straight Dope, here: https://www.straightdope.com/21341675/where-does-the-suffix-arama-as-in-foodarama-come-from

Summarizing: Originally derives from “panorama” (from the Greek *pan*, all, plus *horama*, view). The -arama suffix was then attached to a lot more words (cinorama, diorama, etc.) forming a pattern, which eventually led to -arama being attached to cinema processes, etc.

This is a bad summary, please read the article :)

Comment: Can you explain the linked article a little more in your own words?  Unfortunately, linkrot happens; if this link disappears, future readers won't get any benefit.  Thanks.

Comment: Nice article

Comment: @Billare--that's a great suggestion. It's quite a long article, but I should take time to summarize it.

Comment: That page now redirects to https://www.straightdope.com/21341675/where-does-the-suffix-arama-as-in-foodarama-come-from

Answer (score -1):

while all the other explanations are quite good, i would posture that the suffix -rama belongs, after all others, to neologism. 
email is electronic mail. neologism. two words making one new word. beshews. bear cashews. synergy. synchronized energy.

when someone wants to be cute they add an ending to a word.
in spanish, we say abuela for grandmother. abuela -> abuelita is grammy or gramma, a cute way. 
burro becomes burrito. ito ita those are the cute suffixes.
in english we can add rama to the end.

wordplay is the best foreplay.

Comment: This does not explain how it began.