# I want to use the suffix -orama with rate (rating)

Tags: slang, suffixes

So, I've seen the suffix -arama, but I am also used to -orama, which is the correct to use along 'rate'?

souce: http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/492/where-does-the-suffix-arama-as-in-foodarama-come-from

Comment: Related: _[Suffixing by -rama, orama or arama! How did this begin?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/22244/5822)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use '-orama' or more correctly '-o-rama.' So, 'rate-o-rama.'

Comment: +1. I like the o-rama form because it's more symmetrical and easier to see the pronunciation.

Comment: +1. Agreed. *Ratorama* sounds like fun for rodents though.

Comment: As long as you're aware of the fact that the Greek roots are *(h)ora + ma*...